# How to bind, in Angular 2, null on select input?

Tags: typescript, select, angular2-components

I'm developing one Angular 2 application. This is my view code:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="obj.MyFlag" name="MyFlag" class="form-control col-sm-6">
    <option [value]="null">N/D</option>
    <option [value]="true">SI</option>
    <option [value]="false">NO</option>
</select>
```

Below my component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyDto } from '../../../interfaces';

@Component({
    selector: 'view',
    template: require('./view.component.html')
})
export class MyComponentComponent {
    public obj: MyDto;

    constructor() {
    }

    public Update() {
        console.log(obj.MyFlag); // It return "null" as string but I need that it is null
    }
}

export class MyDto
{
    public MyFlag: boolean;
}
```

I need that if I select first option the *obj.MyFlag* have value null. Actually obj.MyFlag have "null" as string.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem using this syntax:

```
<option value>N/D</option>
<option [value]="true">SI</option>
<option [value]="false">NO</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `undefined` for `[value]` binding instead.

Also you can use the `selected` directive in combination with ngModel to ensure the undefined option is defaulted.

```
    <option [value]="undefined" selected>N/D</option>
    <option [value]="true">SI</option>
    <option [value]="false">NO</option>
```

Make sure your `ngModel` value is undefined on init.

Comment: Hi, If I change my code like suggest you the MyFlag property have "N/D" value (the text option).

Comment: @ilMattion see my update - use undefined for [value] instead

Comment: Hi Daniel, if I use this syntax: [value]=undefined the MyFlag property have "null" value as string.